# Need fast algorithm to compute area of a very small line in a pixel shader

Tags: image-processing, graphics, shader

I'm trying to implement an erosion algorithm on GPU. In part of the algorithm, I need to apply a very small line to a certain texture. In the below picture I want to know what is the area of the line in each pixel. Then I will add the amount to that pixel. The line length is smaller than a pixel and its thickness is one pixel.

[image]

General line algorithms won't work for me since it's a pixel shader (with UAVs) and also it needs to be fast. Having some error like 5% or 10% is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an exact calculation, you would need to find all possible cases how the rectangle might intersect the pixel. Then decompose the area into a couple of primitive shapes and sum up their areas. All pretty easy to mess up and not very performant due to the high number of branching.

An easier way is the following: Generate a number of lines parallel to AB (maybe 5 to 10) and distribute them equally within the rectangle area. Clip all the lines at the pixel, calculate their remaining length, multiply by the width element (rectangle width divided by number of lines) and sum these up. You can control the accuracy with the number of lines. And if this number is constant, the loop will even be unrolled by the compiler and you have significantly less branching.